# How to set redux state from react-token-auth callback

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

So I'm working on a project using the react-token-auth which is configured and exported from a top level function. And the only thing I'm missing is how to get the user's name, email etc. stored into redux for usage across the app. My approach was to decode the JWT token and store it inside the onHydration hook. But I am not able to dispatch outside of a react component. What would be the correct approach? My code looks like this:

```
import { createAuthProvider } from 'react-token-auth';
import jwt_decode from 'jwt-decode'
import { useDispatch } from 'react-redux'
import { setName } from '../store/userSlice';

const dispatch = useDispatch()

export const { useAuth, authFetch, login, logout } =
    createAuthProvider({
        getAccessToken: session => session.access_token,
        storage: localStorage,
        onHydratation: (session) => {
            const decoded = jwt_decode(session.access_token)
            console.log('decoded', decoded)
            dispatch(setName('decoded'))
        },
        onUpdateToken: (token) => fetch('/api/refresh', {
            method: 'POST',
            body: token.access_token
        })
            .then(r => {
                r.json().then(a => {
                    if (!a.error) {
                        return a
                    }
                    else
                        logout()
                })
            })
    });
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since this code is running outside React and not in any React component you won't be able to use the `useDispatch` hook or anything from `react-redux`. Import the instantiated Redux `store` object and directly [dispatch](https://redux.js.org/api/store#dispatchaction) an action to the store.

Example:

```js
import { createAuthProvider } from 'react-token-auth';
import jwt_decode from 'jwt-decode';
import { store } from '../path/to/store';
import { setName } from '../store/userSlice';

export const { useAuth, authFetch, login, logout } = createAuthProvider({
  getAccessToken: session => session.access_token,
  storage: localStorage,
  onHydratation: (session) => {
    const decoded = jwt_decode(session.access_token);
    console.log('decoded', decoded);
    store.dispatch(setName(decoded));
  },
  onUpdateToken: (token) => fetch('/api/refresh', {
    method: 'POST',
    body: token.access_token
  })
    .then(r => r.json())
    .then(a => {
      if (!a.error) {
        return a;
      }
      logout();
    })
});
```